# Induced morphism of proper morphisms.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be a noetherian base scheme. Given two proper flat morphisms of $S$-schemes $f_1: R\to X, f_2: R\to X$, where $X$ is separated over $S$. Then it’s said that the induced morphism $(f_1,f_2):R\to X\times_SX$ is also proper.

By the valuation criterion for properness, given a valuation ring $R$ with quotient field $K$, let $T=\operatorname{Spec}K$, $U=\operatorname{Spec}R$, we have a unique morphism $h_i:U\to R$ in each diagram of $f_i$. And these induce a morphism in the diagram of $R\to X\times _SX$. So, the separatedness of $X$ is unnecessary, right? Thank in advance.

Edit:
Thanks to KReiser, separatedness for $X$ is necessary for conclusion. In fact, it guarantees that projection $p_i: X\times_SX \to X$ is separated by base extension. And the composition $p_i\circ (f_1,f_2):R\to X\times_SX\to X$, which is $f_i$, is proper. Thus we can deduce the properness of $(f_1,f_2)$. By the way, my argument in the earlier post didn’t check any compatible condition for valuable criterion as KReiser said, which proofed nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The separatedness of $X$ is necessary: if $R=X$ and $f_1,f_2=id$, then the induced morphism is the diagonal $\Delta:X\to X\times_SX$, and if $(f_1,f_2)$ were to be proper, then this would mean that the diagonal must be closed, which is a contradiction if $X$ isn't separated over $S$.

It might be instructive for you to write out your argument in more detail if you're curious about exactly where it goes wrong - the main issue is that you haven't verified some compatibility conditions necessary to get the requested valuative criteria diagram for $R\to X\times_SX$. (You should also deal with the fact that your $R$ is pulling double duty here: once as a test scheme and once as a valuation ring.)